# Trying to GET "/iptac-xxxx" not found in nginx log. Is an attack?

Tags: logging, risk-analysis, nginx

I've found some messages like this one, in my nginx error.log.

```
open() "[my-domain]/**iptac-***[a long long string]*/http:/[my-domain]/"
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: , server: , request:
"GET **/iptac-***[a long long string]*
```

I've changed some parts of the message for privacy, but the "long long string" seems to be something like an encrypted string.

Google doesn't know anything about `iptac-`, but I've found a website that reports a very similar URL (please, click on the follow link to see the reported URL with that `iptac`).

https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/db92d481524d4efe6d8f53358d41008c5e3695ded35d3e5f7398f5398779d2c5/analysis/

What is this?

Answer (score 2):

IPTAC usually relate to a Cisco Web Security Appliance.
Can be like a cookie insert for a url redirect.